# For the Hénon map $y_{n+1} = 1 - a{y}_n^{2}+bx_n$ and $x_{n+1} = y_n$, Assess the stability of the period-2 orbit when $b=0.3$ and $a=3.675$.

Tags: recursion, chaos-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

For the Hénon map $y_{n+1} = 1 - a{y}_n^{2}+bx_n$ and $x_{n+1} = y_n$, Assess the stability of the period-2 orbit when $b=0.3$ and $a=3.675$.

I understand that the two points of the orbit must satisfy the equation $a^2y^2-a(1-b)y-a+(1-b)^2=0.$

Accordingly, I have plugged in the values for $a$ and $b$ and solved for the two points $y=0.399634$ and $y=-0.59011$.

I am now unsure how to proceed with assessing the stability of the orbit. I assume it has something to do with the Jacobian and eigenvalues but I would appreciate some guidance with regards to this.

EDIT: So I've calculated the Jacobian to be $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\b&-2ay_n\\\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Yes, start by computing the Jacobian and its eigenvalues at the two points.

Comment: There are other solutions: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-a+y%5E2+%2B+b+x+%3D+x%2C+1-a+%281-a+y%5E2+%2B+b+x%29%5E2+%2B+b+y%3Dy%2C+b%3D0.3%2C+a%3D3.675%2C+solve+for+x%2Cy)

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Should I continue with calculating the eigenvalues of the two solutions I've identified? The hint that accompanies the questions suggests considering the product of the Jacobians in the two points of the period-2 orbit but I'm not sure how this would help in this situation.